# PHP how to loop through multiple comment levels

Tags: php, mysql, loops, nested

My database structure currently looks like this (for a commenting system):

[image]

However, I'm completely lost on how to loop through such data, especially with the nested comments/different levels.

Currently, I loop through the data and display all `level` 0 comments, and for each level 0 comment, loop through and find it's corresponding `level` 1 comment. However, there can be a maximum of 10 levels, and looping through for all 10 the way I am, I feel would be very inefficient.

The `replyTo` column refers to the ID of the comment it is a reply to. If the number is 0, it means the comment is not a reply. So for the table above, for example, I would want to loop through it with PHP to display something as so (from most recent to oldest):

```
hello
    what do you want
    test
        Good!
test
This is a page!
    test
```

Comment: You need a recursive function to read your comments from DB and display them

Comment: Recursion is probably you friend. However this would require a large number of queries and can slow down. Alternative is to change to a nested set model, but this struggles when lots of data is added / deleted (which on a threaded comment system will probably happen many times).

Comment: @Kickstart a lot of queries or read all comments with one query and loop a lot over that array. But probably still faster then fire a query for each comment again to lookup child comments.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER - 1 query is possible, but then you land up having to manually loop through the array to find child records (and as several records could be the child of a parent you couldn't just use parent id as the index of the array). This is something that the database is far better at.

Comment: @Kickstart See the second option of my answer below. I think one query with lot of iterations is much faster then the firing a lot of queries to the DB and grab the results of them. Because the connection to the DB ist most of the time the bottleneck in the application architecure. But I didn't benchmarked it.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER - It will vary with the amount of data. Neither solution is nice for large amounts of data. MySQL has the benefit of indexes, while php has the benefit of not needing to wander off to a potentially different server. Php also has the down side of potentially needing far more memory for large amounts of posts.

Answer (score 0):

Example php script (assuming a database connection class passed to the function).

```
<?php

post_replies($db, 0, 0);

function post_replies($db, $cnt=0, $parent_id=0)
{
    $messages = array();
    $sql = "SELECT id, message
            FROM some_table
            WHERE replyTo = ".(int)$parent_id."
            ORDER BY date";
    $results = $db->query($sql);
    while($row = $db->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $messages[] = $row;
    }
    foreach($messages AS $message)
    {
        echo str_repeat("\t", $cnt).$message['message'];
        post_replies($db, $cnt + 1, $message['id'])
    }
}

?>
```

This could be tweaked a touch to avoid doing a further query for a message that has no replies:-

```
<?php

post_replies($db, 0, 0);

function post_replies($db, $cnt=0, $parent_id=0)
{
    $messages = array();
    $sql = "SELECT a.id, a.message, COUNT(b.id) AS child_count
            FROM some_table a
            LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table b
            ON a.id = b.parent_id
            WHERE a.replyTo = ".(int)$parent_id."
            GROUP BY a.id, a.message
            ORDER BY a.date";
    $results = $db->query($sql);
    while($row = $db->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $messages[] = $row;
    }
    foreach($messages AS $message)
    {
        echo str_repeat("\t", $cnt).$message['message'];
        if ($message['child_count'] > 0)
        {
            post_replies($db, $cnt + 1, $message['id'])
        }
    }
}

?>
```

EDIT

Had a think about this, and decided to have a play. As you have a max number of levels this might be possible with a verbose bit of SQL.

This works by getting all the messages with a replyTo of 0, then UNIONing that with all those with a replyTo of 0 AND child record. and doing the same with a grand child record, etc.

With a bit of a fudge on the sort this brings things back in the right order:-

```
SELECT a.date AS aDate, a.id AS aId, 
        b0.date AS b0Date, b0.id AS b0Id, 
        b1.date AS b1Date, b1.id AS b1Id, 
        b2.date AS b2Date, b2.id AS b2Id, 
        b3.date AS b3Date, b3.id AS b3Id, 
        b4.date AS b4Date, b4.id AS b4Id, 
        b5.date AS b5Date, b5.id AS b5Id, 
        b6.date AS b6Date, b6.id AS b6Id, 
        b7.date AS b7Date, b7.id AS b7Id, 
        b8.date AS b8Date, b8.id AS b8Id, 
        CONCAT(REPEAT('-', 9), b8.message)
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b0 ON a.id = b0.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b1 ON b0.id = b1.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b2 ON b1.id = b2.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b3 ON b2.id = b3.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b4 ON b3.id = b4.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b5 ON b4.id = b5.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b6 ON b5.id = b6.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b7 ON b6.id = b7.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b8 ON b7.id = b8.replyTo
WHERE a.replyTo = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT a.date AS aDate, a.id AS aId, 
        b0.date AS b0Date, b0.id AS b0Id, 
        b1.date AS b1Date, b1.id AS b1Id, 
        b2.date AS b2Date, b2.id AS b2Id, 
        b3.date AS b3Date, b3.id AS b3Id, 
        b4.date AS b4Date, b4.id AS b4Id, 
        b5.date AS b5Date, b5.id AS b5Id, 
        b6.date AS b6Date, b6.id AS b6Id, 
        b7.date AS b7Date, b7.id AS b7Id, 
        NULL AS b8Date, NULL AS b8Id, 
        CONCAT(REPEAT('-', 8), b7.message)
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b0 ON a.id = b0.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b1 ON b0.id = b1.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b2 ON b1.id = b2.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b3 ON b2.id = b3.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b4 ON b3.id = b4.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b5 ON b4.id = b5.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b6 ON b5.id = b6.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b7 ON b6.id = b7.replyTo
WHERE a.replyTo = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT a.date AS aDate, a.id AS aId, 
        b0.date AS b0Date, b0.id AS b0Id, 
        b1.date AS b1Date, b1.id AS b1Id, 
        b2.date AS b2Date, b2.id AS b2Id, 
        b3.date AS b3Date, b3.id AS b3Id, 
        b4.date AS b4Date, b4.id AS b4Id, 
        b5.date AS b5Date, b5.id AS b5Id, 
        b6.date AS b6Date, b6.id AS b6Id, 
        NULL AS b7Date, NULL AS b7Id, 
        NULL AS b8Date, NULL AS b8Id, 
        CONCAT(REPEAT('-', 7), b6.message)
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b0 ON a.id = b0.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b1 ON b0.id = b1.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b2 ON b1.id = b2.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b3 ON b2.id = b3.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b4 ON b3.id = b4.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b5 ON b4.id = b5.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b6 ON b5.id = b6.replyTo
WHERE a.replyTo = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT a.date AS aDate, a.id AS aId, 
        b0.date AS b0Date, b0.id AS b0Id, 
        b1.date AS b1Date, b1.id AS b1Id, 
        b2.date AS b2Date, b2.id AS b2Id, 
        b3.date AS b3Date, b3.id AS b3Id, 
        b4.date AS b4Date, b4.id AS b4Id, 
        b5.date AS b5Date, b5.id AS b5Id, 
        NULL AS b6Date, NULL AS b6Id, 
        NULL AS b7Date, NULL AS b7Id, 
        NULL AS b8Date, NULL AS b8Id, 
        CONCAT(REPEAT('-', 6), b5.message)
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b0 ON a.id = b0.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b1 ON b0.id = b1.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b2 ON b1.id = b2.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b3 ON b2.id = b3.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b4 ON b3.id = b4.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b5 ON b4.id = b5.replyTo
WHERE a.replyTo = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT a.date AS aDate, a.id AS aId, 
        b0.date AS b0Date, b0.id AS b0Id, 
        b1.date AS b1Date, b1.id AS b1Id, 
        b2.date AS b2Date, b2.id AS b2Id, 
        b3.date AS b3Date, b3.id AS b3Id, 
        b4.date AS b4Date, b4.id AS b4Id, 
        NULL AS b5Date, NULL AS b5Id, 
        NULL AS b6Date, NULL AS b6Id, 
        NULL AS b7Date, NULL AS b7Id, 
        NULL AS b8Date, NULL AS b8Id, 
        CONCAT(REPEAT('-', 5), b4.message)
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b0 ON a.id = b0.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b1 ON b0.id = b1.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b2 ON b1.id = b2.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b3 ON b2.id = b3.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b4 ON b3.id = b4.replyTo
WHERE a.replyTo = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT a.date AS aDate, a.id AS aId, 
        b0.date AS b0Date, b0.id AS b0Id, 
        b1.date AS b1Date, b1.id AS b1Id, 
        b2.date AS b2Date, b2.id AS b2Id, 
        b3.date AS b3Date, b3.id AS b3Id, 
        NULL AS b4Date, NULL AS b4Id, 
        NULL AS b5Date, NULL AS b5Id, 
        NULL AS b6Date, NULL AS b6Id, 
        NULL AS b7Date, NULL AS b7Id, 
        NULL AS b8Date, NULL AS b8Id, 
        CONCAT(REPEAT('-', 4), b3.message)
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b0 ON a.id = b0.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b1 ON b0.id = b1.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b2 ON b1.id = b2.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b3 ON b2.id = b3.replyTo
WHERE a.replyTo = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT a.date AS aDate, a.id AS aId, 
        b0.date AS b0Date, b0.id AS b0Id, 
        b1.date AS b1Date, b1.id AS b1Id, 
        b2.date AS b2Date, b2.id AS b2Id, 
        NULL AS b3Date, NULL AS b3Id, 
        NULL AS b4Date, NULL AS b4Id, 
        NULL AS b5Date, NULL AS b5Id, 
        NULL AS b6Date, NULL AS b6Id, 
        NULL AS b7Date, NULL AS b7Id, 
        NULL AS b8Date, NULL AS b8Id, 
        CONCAT(REPEAT('-', 3), b2.message)
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b0 ON a.id = b0.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b1 ON b0.id = b1.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b2 ON b1.id = b2.replyTo
WHERE a.replyTo = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT a.date AS aDate, a.id AS aId, 
        b0.date AS b0Date, b0.id AS b0Id, 
        b1.date AS b1Date, b1.id AS b1Id, 
        NULL AS b2Date, NULL AS b2Id, 
        NULL AS b3Date, NULL AS b3Id, 
        NULL AS b4Date, NULL AS b4Id, 
        NULL AS b5Date, NULL AS b5Id, 
        NULL AS b6Date, NULL AS b6Id, 
        NULL AS b7Date, NULL AS b7Id, 
        NULL AS b8Date, NULL AS b8Id, 
        CONCAT(REPEAT('-', 2), b1.message)
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b0 ON a.id = b0.replyTo
INNER JOIN some_table b1 ON b0.id = b1.replyTo
WHERE a.replyTo = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT a.date AS aDate, a.id AS aId, 
        b0.date AS b0Date, b0.id AS b0Id, 
        NULL AS b1Date, NULL AS b1Id, 
        NULL AS b2Date, NULL AS b2Id, 
        NULL AS b3Date, NULL AS b3Id, 
        NULL AS b4Date, NULL AS b4Id, 
        NULL AS b5Date, NULL AS b5Id, 
        NULL AS b6Date, NULL AS b6Id, 
        NULL AS b7Date, NULL AS b7Id, 
        NULL AS b8Date, NULL AS b8Id, 
        CONCAT(REPEAT('-', 1), b0.message)
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN some_table b0 ON a.id = b0.replyTo
WHERE a.replyTo = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT a.date AS aDate, a.id AS aId, 
        NULL AS b0Date, NULL AS b0Id, 
        NULL AS b1Date, NULL AS b1Id, 
        NULL AS b2Date, NULL AS b2Id, 
        NULL AS b3Date, NULL AS b3Id, 
        NULL AS b4Date, NULL AS b4Id, 
        NULL AS b5Date, NULL AS b5Id, 
        NULL AS b6Date, NULL AS b6Id, 
        NULL AS b7Date, NULL AS b7Id, 
        NULL AS b8Date, NULL AS b8Id, 
        a.message
FROM some_table a
WHERE a.replyTo = 0
ORDER BY aDate DESC, aID, 
        IFNULL(b0Date, '2099-12-31') DESC, b0Id, 
        IFNULL(b1Date, '2099-12-31') DESC, b1Id, 
        IFNULL(b2Date, '2099-12-31') DESC, b2Id, 
        IFNULL(b3Date, '2099-12-31') DESC, b3Id, 
        IFNULL(b4Date, '2099-12-31') DESC, b4Id, 
        IFNULL(b5Date, '2099-12-31') DESC, b5Id, 
        IFNULL(b6Date, '2099-12-31') DESC, b6Id, 
        IFNULL(b7Date, '2099-12-31') DESC, b7Id, 
        IFNULL(b8Date, '2099-12-31') DESC, b8Id
```

SQL fiddle for it:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/775405/12

Comment: Done a change to demonstrate a possibly (but very long winded) way of doing this in a single piece of SQL without the need to repeatedly loop through an array of all the records returned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to options:

**Lot of queries**

You just select the comments you need in the loop:

```
<?php

function displayCommentsRecursive($stmnt, $replyTo = 0) {
    // Select the top comments first
    $stmnt->execute(array(0));
    $result = $stmnt->fetchAll();

    foreach($result as $res) {
        // display comment
        echo $res->user , ': ' , $res->text;

        echo displayCommentsRecursive($res->ID);
    }
}

$stmntGetComments = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT ID, user, text
    FROM comment
    WHERE replyTo = ?
");

displayCommentsRecursive($stmntGetComments);
```

**Lot of iteration**

You fire the query just once and pick the comments you need out of the "comment pool":

```
<?php

function displayCommentsRecursive(array $comments, $replyTo = 0) {
    foreach($result as $res) {
        if($replyTo != $res->replyTo)
            continue;

        // display comment
        echo $res->user , ': ' , $res->text;

        echo displayCommentsRecursive($comments, $res->ID);
    }
}

$stmntGetComments = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT ID, user, text, replyTo
    FROM comment
");

// Select all comments at once
$stmntGetComments->execute(array(0));
$comments = $stmntGetComments->fetchAll();

displayCommentsRecursive($comments);
```